# How to pass IDs of the selected Kendo grid rows to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have an MVC 4 project with a Kendo grid. The grid is multi-selectable. How can I pass IDs of the selected rows to the controller on button click?

Thanks.

Here is my grid:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Manifest)
      .Name("PackageGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p=>p.PackageId).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(p => p.PackageName)
              .Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(@item.PackageName,"PackageDetails","ExternalIntegration", new {id=@item.PackageId}, null)</text>);
          columns.Bound(p => p.NumberOfDaysAgo);
          columns.Bound(p => p.LastEvent);
          columns.Bound(p=>p.ProcessDate);
          columns.Bound(p=>p.ProcessTime).Title("Process Time(ms)");
          columns.Bound(p=>p.DomainMessageCount);
          columns.Bound(p => p.FailureParseEventCount).Title("Items of Concern");
      })
                            .Sortable()
                            .Filterable(filterConfig => filterConfig
                                .Messages(messageConfig => messageConfig
                                    .Filter("Apply")
                                    .Info("Set Filter")))
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Server()
                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.PackageId))
                          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can have multiple row selection you can use `select()` method and it will return an array of rows you have selected. Then you can access row values as below inside your button click event.

```
var packageGrid = $("#PackageGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var rows = packageGrid.select();
rows.each(function(index, row) {
  var selectedItem = packageGrid.dataItem(row);
  // var packageName= selectedItem.PackageName;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please clarify how the selected ids are to be passed to the controller? I don't see (or don't understand) this part.

Comment: Never mind, I will figure it out. You gave me the main part, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I still have a difficulty with this. I cannot get the PackageId out of the selectedItem...

Comment: What do you get when you put `selectedItem.PackageId` ?

Comment: I get Undefined. BTW, PackageId is guid. Not sure if this matters.

Comment: Please check the generated HTML and let me know the tag you can see related to `PackageId`.

Comment: server","filter":[],"schema":{"data":"Data","total":"Total","errors":"Errors","model":{"id":"PackageId","fields":{"PackageId":{"type":"string"},"IntegrationAttemptId":{"type":"string"},"SourceContainerId":{"type":"string"},"PackageName":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Partner":{"type":"string"},"PackageType":{"type":"string"},"Direction":{"type":"string"},"NumberOfDaysAgo":{"type":"number"},"ProcessDate":{"type":"date","defaultValue":null},"ProcessTime":{"type":"number"},"FailureParseEventCount":{"type":"number","defaul

Comment: Can you paste one `tr` tag in HTML. e.g. `<tr role="row" ... <td role="....">...</td>...</tr>`

Comment: <tr class="k-master-row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="k-icon k-plus" href="#"></a></td><td style="display:none">3f37ad5f-1f45-4018-b6ce-af2a513679b0</td><td><a href="/one/two/3f37ad5f-1f45-4018-b6ce-af2a513679b0">Sent</a></td><td>18</td><td>3</td><td>6/23/2014</td><td>0</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="k-detail-row " style="display:none"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell">&nbsp;</td><td class="k-detail-cell" colspan="7">
<script>jQuery(function(){jQuery("#panel_3f37ad5f-1f45-4018-b6ce-af2a513679b0").kendoPanelBar({"expandMode":"multiple"});});
</script>
</td></tr>

Comment: In above HTML is `3f37ad5f-1f45-4018-b6ce-af2a513679b0` your PackageId ? And what do you get when you put `selectedItem.uid` ?

Comment: I am getting an exception on var selectedItem = packageGrid.dataItem(row); The error message is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined". And property 2 is in kendo.slider.js

Comment: And when I try to step into packageGrid.dataItem(row);, I get "GET http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/src/js/kendo.slider.js 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Unfortunately, no. On "var selectedItem = packageGrid.dataItem(row);" it gives me the same exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined". And the same thing happens if I use single selection mode.